# Combine/merge more than two objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, merge

I have many objects like this.

```
$('input[id^=ppu]');
$('input[id^=lpu]');
$('input[id^=nun]');
$('input[id^=lt]'); 
$('input[id^=bap]');
$('input[id^=pa]');
```

how to combine/merge them with jquery.

Comment: comma seperate them inside $('input[id^=ppu], input[id^=lpu], etc')

Comment: or give them a common class and select that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma to separate the selectors:

```
$('input[id^=ppu], input[id^=lpu], input[id^=nun], input[id^=lt], input[id^=bap], input[id^=pa]')
```

Or use `add()`:

```
$('input[id^=ppu]')
    .add('input[id^=lpu]')
    .add('input[id^=nun]')
    .add('input[id^=lt]') 
    .add('input[id^=bap]')
    .add('input[id^=pa]')
```

Or better yet, modify your HTML so that you can select all those elements by `class` which will be much quicker.